# How to install Pop Shell on Ubuntu 21.10 or 22.04?

Tags: gnome

I have 2 new computers and installed Pop Shell on either Ubuntu 21.10 or 22.04 by following [Using Pop Shell on other GNOME Desktops](https://support.system76.com/articles/pop-shell/)

```
sudo apt install git node-typescript make 
git clone https://github.com/pop-os/shell.git 
cd shell 
make local-install
```

There is no icon of Pop Shell on the top panel after the installation and moreover, the monitor did not wake up after sleep.
What should be done next to get Pop Shell work ?

Comment: Do you want to get it to work or do you want to remove it?

Comment: @Organic Marble I really want to get it to work.

Comment: @vanadium Edited Subject and Question already. I just want to get Pop Shell to work. Help me please.

Comment: Do you see an option to use Pop Shell when you click on this cog icon? https://i.stack.imgur.com/me4xe.png (this is from a slightly older version of Ubuntu, and may have changed)

Answer (score 2):

Currently *pop-os* shell extension uses a certain order of installation steps, that does not work when extension was never install before on your distro (which is the case for fresh Ubuntu installations)

It seems that a change that "fixes" it already exists, but has been dropped for some reasons unclear to me. You can, however, apply it manually, and retry your installation attempt:

```
sudo apt install git node-typescript make 
git clone https://github.com/pop-os/shell.git 
git cherry-pick 425f1e4dd851017be80b83cd3eeda803f0ac8f1f
cd shell 
make local-install
```

This worked for me - I have *pop-os* shell extension running on *Ubuntu 22.04*.

**DISCLAIMER1**: 425f1e4dd8 applies cleanly on 15e7acfc8d. This may not be the case in future, if codebase changes

**DISCLAIMER2**: *pop-os* shell extension may conflict with some of the default gnome-shell shortcuts. It tries hard to fix that, but at least in my case I have some issues when moving apps between workspaces

reference: https://github.com/pop-os/shell/issues/760

Comment: After I installed GNOME Tweaks, this got Pop Shell to work. Is this the right way ?

Comment: Shouldn't `cd shell` occur before `git cherry-pick` so as to run the cherry-pick within the context of the git repository?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04. Fails at `Extension “pop-shell@system76.com” does not exist`

Comment: I have installed it without any cherry-picking, and had to reboot my machine in order to get access back to my desktop. Then, using the GNOME Shell extensions, I have enabled it, like @IvyCap said in his answser, and then it works like a charm. I'm running the commit `b5acccefcaa653791d25f70a22c0e04f1858d96e`.

Comment: The Pop launcher was not working (no results, blank) because the `pop-launcher` binary was not installed. After building it from the sources, it now works fine!

Answer (score 1):

For me I needed to enable Pop Shell in Gnome Extensions for the icon to show.

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

[image]

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you.